# Is there any way to set the delegate of a UINavigationBar in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uinavigationbar

If I'm using a `UINavigationBar` without a `UINavigationController` and I'm laying it out in a storyboard, and I want to set the delegate, do I have to make an outlet and attach the delegate on `viewDidLoad` or is there some way that I'm missing to attach my view controller as a delegate for `UINavigationBar` declaratively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to drag from the Outlets view in IB to the ViewController and set that as the delegate. See attached.

[image: Connect delegate for UINavigationBar in InterfaceBuilder]

Comment: You totally can -- or in the popup window for the outlets. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! Glad it helped!!